# How to exclude an element from an array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a v-for to display all my categories. I would like to exclude a category, this category has an id = 1. So basically how can I remove by Id ? or maybe how can I exclude the first element of the array ? what do I do ?

```
<div class="list" v-for="(category,index ) in Categories" :key="category.id">
```

Comment: basically how do I get all the category ids > 1 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [v-if](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if).

```
<div class="list" v-for="(category,index ) in Categories" :key="category.id">
  <template v-if="category.id === 1">
    ...
```

Comment: you cant use v-if with v-for in one div, you can use <template> instead <div>

Comment: I don't really get what you mean... sorry im very new to this. where do I add the v-if ?
<div class="list" v-for="(category,index ) in Categories":key="category.id">

Comment: can you update your whole codebase in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Use computed property component option.

```
computed: {
    filteredCategories: function(){
       //example ids to ignore 
       var ignore = [1, 10];
        return this.categories.filter(cat => ignore.indexOf(cat.id) === -1);
    }
}

<div class="list" v-for="(category,index ) in filteredCategories" :key="category.id">
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all categories with an `id` greater than 1, the cleanest way would be to have a filteredCategories computed:

```
<div class="list" v-for="category in filteredCategories" :key="category.id" />
```

```js
computed: {
  filteredCategories: {
    return this.Categories.filter(cat => cat.id > 1);
  }
}
```

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    Categories: [
      {id: 1, name: 'I won\'t get rendered!'},
      {id: 2, name: 'Second category'},
      {id: 3, name: 'Third category'},
      {id: 4, name: 'Fourth category'},
      {id: 0, name: 'I won\'t get rendered, either. My id is `0`'}
    ]
  }),
  computed: {
    filteredCategories() {
      return this.Categories.filter(cat => cat.id > 1);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="list" v-for="category in filteredCategories" :key="category.id">
    {{category.id}} - {{ category.name }}
  </div>
</div>
```

The advantages are:

- the initial `Categories` array is not mutated, so if you use it anywhere else in the component it will still contain all categories (which is not true if you filter using `.splice`)
- the filtering is done based on the value of `id`, not on the category position in the array.

---

Here's how to get the Categories from the api:

```js
data: () => ({
  Categories: []
}),
computed: {
  filteredCategories() {
    return this.Categories.filter(cat => cat.id > 1);
  }
},
mounted() {
  axios.get("path/to/your/api")
    .then(response => this.Categories = response.data);
}
```

Comment: yes thanks, but I am trying to get them fromt he api, that seems a bit more complicated for me. here is my code, where do I place the computed ?                                                 
  async mounted() this.Categories = await axios.get("http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/")
    .then(response => {
      return response.data
    })

Comment: Updated answer. In short: declare `Categories` in `data` as empty array. Populate it when you have the data. The `filteredCategories` will work.